# Having trouble playing a wav file vb net

Tags: vb.net

I am using a function to return a string with the path of the *.wav file I would like to play.

Here is the function used to determine which sound to play when the user clicks on something and etc...

```
Function GetSoundPath() As String
    Dim theme As String, appPath As String, soundPath As String
    theme = GetUserTheme()
    appPath = LCase(Application.StartupPath & "\themes\" & theme & "\sounds\click.wav")

    Return soundPath

End Function
```

The above function gets the correct path to the *.wav file needed to be played. The issue is that when I use my function with "My.Computer.Audio.Play(GetSoundPath)" I get an error speaking of:

> An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: The form referred to itself during construction from a default instance, which led to infinite recursion.  Within the Form's constructor refer to the form using 'Me.'

I have checked the application.vb file and no references to my form as its name "wisealarm" was found. The form was referred to as "Me" as it should be. The even stranger thing is that when I manually type the path in the command it works without issue.. e.x. My.Computer.Audio.Play("c:\users\sound.wav")

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. If any further code or details are needed please let me know. thanks.

Comment: where do you set `soundPath` for it to return a meaningful value?

Comment: Look at the stack trace of the exception, especially the one for the InnerException.  If that doesn't help then post it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is something in the initialization of the form that causes an error, such as an initialization of a class. If the error is occurring in this function, you can move the call (or initialization with "New") outside the Dim (or equivalent) statement for more normal debugging. This may be in the form_load function.

Also, you're returning an undefined variable SoundPath -- maybe you should replace appPath with SoundPath in the assignment statement.